# Is there a way to say the two best?

Tags: words, english-to-japanese

Is there a way to say the two best? Like "the two best seasons are..." or something similar. I'm trying to say

> The two best times to visit Nara are October/November (fall) and March/April/May (spring).

But I only know 一番. I would love the help. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 8):

As a prefix, you could use 二大｛にだい｝- as in something like 二大政党: two major parties.

As a predicate, 双璧｛そうへき｝ e.g. 奈良を訪れる（に あたって）一番いい時期（として）は、春と秋が双璧だ (though it's pointless to apply it to 2 out of only 4). You could modify a noun through a form of 双璧を成す｛なす｝ like 奈良を訪れるにあたって双璧をなす季節｛きせつ｝は…, but it's extravagant and rather nonsensical to your example.

So, you might want to settle down with 奈良を訪れる一番いい時期は秋と春だ or so. If being two is important, you have to somehow express it like 奈良を訪れる一番いい時期を２つ選べと言われたら.

Comment: That makes so much more sense! Thank you for the help.